# How to refer to an element from a function (called from an event listener)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I add a class to an object of a specific class upon click? The elements that should gain an extra class contain the "date" class.

```
$(".date").bind("click",addClass());

function addClass(){
//objectClicked.className+=""
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to identify the exact element that was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a jQuery event handler, `this` is bound to the source element of the event, so your can use `$(this).addClass('yourClass');` to add the new class to the clicked element.

```
$(".date").bind("click", addClass);

function addClass() {
    $(this).addClass('yourClass');
}
```

Also, watch out that you don't invoke the `addClass` function in the call to `bind`. That won't work. You need to pass the function itself as I have.

Answer (score 0):

Though FishBasketGordo answer is a working solutions, you can also do it this way :

```
$(".date").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("yourClass");
});
```